# Powershell user authorizations

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

When running the following command in Powershell it works only if logged in as the local admin or if run from a remote machine and passing the local admin account credentials:

```
schtasks /s (machine) /u (administrator) /p (the password) /tn (the task I'm interested in getting information on)
```

From a remote machine the reply back is

> Error: Access is Denied.

When logged into the machine with an account other than the local administrator the answer back is

> Error: The system cannot find the pat specified.

I'd like to get either method working.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a task you have to use

```
schtasks /run ...
```

Otherwise you'll get the `system cannot find the path specified` error. Also, as a non-admin user you don't have access to scheduled tasks running in the context of another user. You have to either change the task to run as your own user, or keep authenticating with admin credentials.